# Get the device name of connected USB disk

Tags: shell-script, usb, path

I need to get the device names of all connected USB disks (ie `sdd`).

I have 3 USB disks plugged in, and 2 SATA disks:

```
$ find /sys/devices/ -name block        
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-5/4-5:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block
```

I want to ignore the SATA disks, but I need to list all the USB disks.

In the terminal, I can us `ls` and it will give me `sdd`:

```
$ ls /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block
sdd
```

But I need to use this in a script. I need to iterate over all USB disks, and I don't know the exact path in advance, so I have to use wildcards (`*` or `?`):

```
for DISK in $(ls /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb?/*/*:1.0/host?/target?:0:0/?:0:0:0/block) ; do
echo /dev/$DISK
done
```

the above only works if one USB disk is plugged in. If two or more disks are plugend in, I get `sdd` as well as the `/sys` path, which I don't want, ie:

```
/dev//sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block:
/dev/sdd
/dev//sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block:
/dev/sde
/dev//sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-5/4-5:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block:
/dev/sdc
```

how can I iterate only over `sdd` `sde` `sdc` ?

I am looking for a solution not using `udev` infrastructure, ie `/dev/disk/by-path/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with `lsblk` command.

`lsblk -l -o name,tran` gives

```
NAME TRAN
sda  sata
sda1 
sdb  usb
sdc  usb
sr0  sata
```

`-l` stands for "list" format, so it's easier to parse. Otherwise, you would get a tree format like this:

```
NAME   TRAN
sda    sata
└─sda1
sdb    usb
sr0    sata
```

Specifying other flags will give you more information like FSTYPE, LABEL, UUID, MOUNTPOINT and many other, just run `lsblk --help` to see all options.

You may want to use `--paths --noheadings --scsi` flags to  have output printed like this:

```
sata   /dev/sda
usb    /dev/sdb
usb    /dev/sdc
sata   /dev/sr0
```

and then `grep` over the input to filter out those lines with usb at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 4):

Do `lsusb`, it gives the name of the devices connected via the USB bus.

As in:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0421:0802 Nokia Mobile Phones CA-42 Phone Parent
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

See also [man lsusb](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsusb)

> Description
>
> lsusb is a utility for displaying information about USB buses in the
>   system and the devices connected to them.

Comment: thanks, but how can i use that in my `for loop` example ?